# Can i use only _ (underscore) for the name of the class?

Tags: php, oop

Can i use only _ (underscore) for the name of the class if yes then how object will be create and if no then why not?

```
 class _{

   }
```

Comment: try and see what happens

Comment: I don't know why this question get up voted while it should be down voted

Comment: @rajeshpatel could you mark one answer as accepted to mark this question answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use only underscore for the class name.

```
class _{
  function __construct(){
    echo 'It works!';
  }
}

new _();
```

Output:

```
It works!
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/61d12ee454f032e5c014c9fb5f0c11de1afb7f10)</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) might be your best friend.

> The class name can be any valid label, provided it is not a PHP
>   reserved word. A valid class name starts with a letter or underscore,
>   followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a
>   regular expression, it would be expressed thus:
>   ^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$.

Regex test: https://regex101.com/r/lY2aJ4/1